# Using SQL ORDER to work dynamically

Tags: mysql

I'm using PHP to make SQL queries and thought that it'd be a lot easier to query my results rather than calculate them with PHP.

This is my demo table:

```
ID | m1 | m2 | m3 | result
1  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 6
2  | 2  | 3  | 1  | 6
3  | 4  | 8  | 4  | 16
4  | 4  | 5  | 7  | 16
```

What i'd like to achieve is to order them based on result, if these are the same, then minimum of `(m1,m2,m3)`, if that's the same then eliminate the minimum and continue and if by chance all the values are same, then order by ID.

So for example based on my table:

```
SELECT * FROM demotable ORDER BY result,min(m1,m2,m3) --And no more ideas..
```

The results should be ordered as follows:

```
ID | m1 | m2 | m3 | result
1  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 6    
2  | 2  | 3  | 1  | 6
4  | 4  | 5  | 7  | 16
3  | 4  | 8  | 4  | 16
```

So firstly it checks `results` and sees that 6 and  6 is the same. After that it takes the `minimum of (m1,m2,m3)` sees that it's the same as well. For first it removes `m1` (as it's the minimum) and second it removes `m3` (as it's the minimum). Then does `min(m2,m3)` & `min(m1,m2)` and these are also same. Now there's only one field to compare left by "coincidence" these are also same and now it's ordered by ID.

On bottom end of the table we have also matching `result` and `min(m1,m2,m3)` are same. When `m1` is eliminated (as being lowest for both) `min(m2,m3)` gives different values and thus element with `ID 4` is higher than element with `ID 3`.

Is it feasible and or possible to do something like that with SQL or should i just select all my data into array and do the calculation in PHP?

Edit based on Giorgios answer:

If i have data:

```
ID | m1 | m2 | m3 | result
1  | 4  | 4  | 2  | 10
2  | 2  | 2  | 6  | 10
```

Then the ID 1 is returned as best not ID 2, however it should be ID2.

Comment: AFAIK, the min() function finds the minimum value among a set of rows, not a list of values. The least() function can be used for that. Also, instead of max(), you would use greatest().

Comment: You might be able create an _order-by-score_ of some sort for each row, and use that in the `order by``` clause. For example, ```IF(m1 = least(m1,m2,m3),least(m2,m3),least(m1,m2,m3))```. Only part of what you describe, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to find the smallest, middle and greatest value among `m1, m2, m3` and sort by these values:

```
ORDER BY result,
         LEAST(m1,m2,m3),
         IF(m1 <> LEAST(m1,m2,m3) AND m1 <> GREATEST(m1, m2,m3), m1,
            IF(((m1 = m2) OR 
                (m2 = m3) OR 
                (m2 > m1 AND m2 < m3 OR m2 > m3 AND m2 < m1)), m2, m3)),
         GREATEST(m1, m2, m3),
         ID
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/GHTHH60067)

Comment: It seems you've forgot to close the first IF.

Comment: Ahh, no problem, i wanted to edit myself. Seems to be working though, i'm just digesting on how it works :)

Comment: Hey @Giorgos, it seems that in one case (see my edit) it does not work.

Comment: @Banana Please check the edit I made. It should work now.

Answer (score 3):

cluld be that instead  of min you use least

```
  SELECT * FROM demotable ORDER BY result, least(m1,m2,m3)
```

Comment: Wow, so simple and elegant, really stupid question when come to think of it.

Comment: There are no stupid questions .. there are things that you know and others do not .. and ask is a good way to learn

Comment: I don't think this will work according to the requirement of the OP. For example in the second group the query will order records using: `ORDER BY 16, 4`. So, the output will be arbitrary. It could be that `ID=3` comes first.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, it seems you're correct and the solution is not so simple and elegant :(